# 2 column table, ignore duplicates on mass insert postgresql

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have a Join table in Rails which is just a 2 column table with ids.

In order to mass insert into this table, I use

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("INSERT INTO myjointable (first_id,second_id) VALUES #{values})
```

Unfortunately this gives me errors when there are duplicates. I don't need to update any values, simply move on to the next `insert` if a duplicate exists.

How would I do this?

As an fyi I have searched stackoverflow and most the answers are a bit advanced for me to understand. I've also checked the postgresql documents and played around in the rails console but still to no avail. I can't figure this one out so i'm hoping someone else can help tell me what I'm doing wrong.

The closest statement I've tried is:

```
INSERT INTO myjointable (first_id,second_id) SELECT 1,2 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
         SELECT first_id FROM myjointable 
       WHERE first_id = 1 AND second_id IN (...))
```

Part of the problem with this statement is that I am only inserting 1 value at a time whereas I want a statement that mass inserts. Also the `second_id IN (...)` section of the statement can include up to 100 different values so I'm not sure how slow that will be.

Note that for the most part there should not be many duplicates so I am not sure if mass inserting to a temporary table and finding distinct values is a good idea.

Edit to add context:

The reason I need a mass insert is because I have a many to many relationship between 2 models where 1 of the models is never populated by a form. I have stocks, and stock price histories. The stock price histories are never created in a form, but rather mass inserted themselves by pulling the data from YahooFinance with their yahoo finance API. I use the activerecord-import gem to mass insert for stock price histories (i.e. Model.import columns,values) but I can't type jointable.import columns,values because I get the `jointable is an undefined local variable`

Comment: It's not clear what the problems is you are trying to solve.  For example, why are you needing to do a mass insert using custom SQL?  What is the context?

Comment: @muttonlamb I've added the reason I need mass insertion using a custom SQL

Comment: In future please always specify your PostgreSQL version and where possible provide some sample data or an SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd tackle it: Create a temp table and populate it with your new values. Then lock the old join values table to prevent concurrent modification (important) and insert all value pairs that appear in the new table but not the old one.

One way to do this is by doing a left outer join of the old values onto the new ones and filtering for rows where the old join table values are null. Another approach is to use an `EXISTS` subquery. The two are highly likely to result in the same query plan once the query optimiser is done with them anyway.

Example, untested (since you didn't provide an SQLFiddle or sample data) but should work:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newjoinvalues(
    first_id integer,
    second_id integer,
    primary key(first_id,second_id)
);

-- Now populate `newjoinvalues` with multi-valued inserts or COPY
COPY newjoinvalues(first_id, second_id) FROM stdin;

LOCK TABLE myjoinvalues IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

INSERT INTO myjoinvalues
SELECT n.first_id, n.second_id
FROM newjoinvalues n 
LEFT OUTER JOIN myjoinvalues m ON (n.first_id = m.first_id AND n.second_id = m.second_id)
WHERE m.first_id IS NULL AND m.second_id IS NULL;

COMMIT;
```

This won't update existing values, but you can do that fairly easily too by using with a second query that does an `UPDATE ... FROM` while still holding the write table lock.

Note that the lock mode specified above will not block `SELECT`s, only writes like `INSERT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, so queries can continue to be made to the table while the process is ongoing, you just can't update it.

If you can't accept that an alternative is to run the update in `SERIALIZABLE` isolation (only works properly for this purpose in Pg 9.1 and above). This will result in the query failing whenever a concurrent write occurs so you have to be prepared to retry it over and over and over again. For that reason it's likely to be better to just live with locking the table for a while.

Comment: I decided to use a WITH clause which selected my values and gave them a name (it's almost as if it created a temporary table). Then I `Insert Into table Select * From withqueryname WHERE NOT EXISTS` and used `WHERE NOT EXISTS(defining a query to see if it is in my table)` to effectively skip any inserts which were already in the table. Would my method be more or less efficient than yours?

Comment: @Chowza Your approach is fine for smaller sets of new values; for bigger sets of new values you start to need an index on the set of new values and the sheer size of the SQL expression to parse becomes a problem. If you expect lots (hundreds+) of new values you should use a temp table rather than a `VALUES` expression in a `WITH` clause. Either way, re efficiency compare with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and see. Doing it all in one SQL statement does *not* avoid the need for the lock.

Comment: Sorry Craig, one more question. If I write `ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('LOCK TABLE jointable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE') ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('my sql statement above') end` will this satisfy the issue with concurrent modifications?

Comment: @Chowza So long as both occur in the same transaction then yes that'll do the job. I don't work with ActiveRecord so I can't confirm that part. If you're unsure if two statements run in the same transaction a useful trick is to do: `DECLARE test CURSOR FOR SELECT 1;` followed by `FETCH ALL FROM test;`. This will only succeed if the two run in the same transaction, since the cursor isn't accessible even in the same session after end of transaction scope.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using the `WITH` clause to select my values and give it a name. Then I inserted those values and used `WHERE NOT EXISTS` to effectively skip any items that are already in my database.

So far it looks like it is working...

```
WITH withqueryname(first_id,second_id) AS (VALUES(1,2),(3,4),(5,6)...etc) 
INSERT INTO jointablename (first_id,second_id) 
SELECT * FROM withqueryname 
WHERE NOT EXISTS( 
      SELECT first_id FROM jointablename WHERE 
             first_id = 1 AND 
             second_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6..etc))
```

You can interchange the Values with a variable. Mine was `VALUES#{values}`

You can also interchange the second_id IN with a variable. Mine was `second_id IN #{variable}`.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `second_id IN (...list...)` clause. You already have that information in `withqueryname` and do not need to repeat it. Additionally, `FROM ... WHERE` is really bad style; use `FROM firsttable INNER JOIN secondtable ON (condition)`. Overall this looks unnecessarily complex for what it does, though I suspect the query planner will optimise it to the same plan as a `left outer join` based approach once you get rid of the repetition of the `second_id` list. `explain analyze` and see.

Comment: @CraigRinger Thanks for your help and advice. I've implemented the INNER Join now. I am also looking to add a lock because I didn't think about concurrent imports. I will accept your answer because it appears to be the more 'appropriate' and 'clean' way of handling duplicates.